# Pandas: Query tool doesn't work if column headers are tuples: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

TLDR: The df.query() tool doesn't seem to work if the df's columns are tuples or even tuples converted into strings. How can I work around this to get the slice I'm aiming for?

---

**Long Version:** I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this (although there are a lot more columns and rows...):

```
> dosage_df

Score   ("A_dose","Super")  ("A_dose","Light")  ("B_dose","Regular")
28              1               40              130
11              2               40              130
72              3               40              130
67              1               90              130
74              2               90              130
89              3               90              130
43              1               40              700
61              2               40              700
5               3               40              700
```

Along with my data frame, I also have a python dictionary with the relevant ranges for each feature. The keys are the feature names, and the different values which it can take are the keys:

```
# Original Version 

dosage_df.columns = ['First Score', 'Last Score', ("A_dose","Super"), ("A_dose","Light"), ("B_dose","Regular")] 

dict_of_dose_ranges = {("A_dose","Super"):[1,2,3],
                       ("A_dose","Light"):[40,70,90],
                       ("B_dose","Regular"):[130,200,500,700]}
```

For my purposes, I need to generate a particular combination (say A_dose = 1, B_dose = 90, and C_dose = 700), and based on those settings take the relevant slice out of my dataframe, and do relevant calculations from that smaller subset, and save the results somewhere.

I'm doing this by implementing the following:

```
from itertools import product

for dosage_comb in product(*dict_of_dose_ranges.values()):
    dosage_items = zip(dict_of_dose_ranges.keys(), dosage_comb)
    query_str = ' & '.join('{} == {}'.format(*x) for x in dosage_items)
    **sub_df = dosage_df.query(query_str)**
    ...
```

**The problem is that is gets hung up on the query step, as it returns the following error message:**

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

In this case, the query generated looks like this:

query_str = "("A_dose","Light") == 40 & ("A_dose","Super") == 1 & ("B_dose","Regular") == 130"

**Troubleshooting Attempts:**

I've confirmed that indeed that solution should work for a dataframe with just string columns as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378510/iterating-across-multiple-colums-in-pandas-df-and-slicing-dynamically). In addition, I've also tried "tricking" the tool by converting the columns and the dictionary keys into strings by the following code... but that returned the same error.

```
# String Version
dosage_df.columns = ['First Score', 'Last Score', '("A_dose","Super")', '("A_dose","Light")', '("B_dose","Regular")']
dict_of_dose_ranges = {
                        '("A_dose","Super")':[1,2,3],
                        '("A_dose","Light")':[40,70,90],
                        '("B_dose","Regular")':[130,200,500,700]}
```

Is there an alternate tool in python that can take tuples as inputs or a different way for me to trick it into working?

Comment: What is the full stacktrace of your error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a list of conditions and logically condense them with [`np.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) instead of using `query`:

```
for dosage_comb in product(*dict_of_dose_ranges.values()):
    dosage_items = zip(dict_of_dose_ranges.keys(), dosage_comb)
    condition = np.all([dosage_df[col] == dose for col, dose in dosage_items], axis=0)
    sub_df = dosage_df[condition]
```

This method seems to be a bit more flexible than `query`, but when filtering across many columns I've found that `query` often performs better.  I don't know if this is true in general though.